# Куда обратится для исправления пакета?

Tags: debian, package

Пол часа мучался с OpenDKIM(пакет именнуется в нижнем регистре) с репозитория Debian sid
Он не в какую не хотел слушать свой дефолтный tcp порт, указывал его в конфиге, а он всё ровно слушает unix сокет.
В htop я заметил что демон запускается с опцией `-p local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`, я заглянул в его systemd юнит и действительно обнаружил там в `ExecStart` опцию `-p local:/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock`, как не сложно догадатся эта опция указует что слушать нужно указанный unix сокет, мне это кажется не правильным, это ломает совместимость со старыми версиями и не соответствует даже инструкции на `wiki.debian.org`, инструкция уж не как не древняя я считаю https://wiki.debian.org/opendkim
В связи с эти есть несколько вопросов:
1. Куда обратится? В описании пакета есть email мейнтейнера, нужно ему на email писать?
2. Есть ли где описание каждого изменения в пакете, то есть могу ли я найти комментарий обьясняющий для чего был добавлен этот аргумент в unit скрипт?
3. Стоит ли сообщать о этом "баге"? Ведь добавлял этот аргумент наверняка лучше разберающийся человек чем я и мне не хотелось бы с ним спорить, а темболее через google translate

Comment: Пиши мантайнеру

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/reportbug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как оказалось я ошибся на счет бага, там unit генерируется динамически и слушающий сокет считуется с /etc/default/opendkim, у меня почему-то не считался и сгенерировался unit с дефолтным unix сокетом, а с файла конфигурации сокет вообще не должен считыватся, точнее он перекрывается передачей опции `-p <сокет считаный с файла /etc/default/opendkim>`, после полной переустановки пакета всё наладилось.

А теперь последовательность действий которую я бы посоветовал желающим отправить багрепорт касающийся какого либо пакета:
1. Попробуйте для начала переустановить полностю пакет и проверить воспроизводится ли баг после этого.
2. Проверте тщательно, действительно ли это баг, а не вы не правильно что-то делаете.
3. Проанализируйте баг чтоб можно было его нормально описать.
4. Ознакомтесь с информацией по данной ссылке https://wiki.debian.org/reportbug  (Спасибо @alexander barakin ).
5. Установите пакет `reportbug`, введите `reportbug <имя пакета с багом>` и следуйте дальнейшим инструкциям.